# Convert base class to derived class when returning object

Tags: c++, boost-python

I have classes and functions which I don't want to change, but I want to expose them to Python with some additional functionalities (Dunder Methods etc.). So what I have is derived class like follows:

**C++**

```
#include "boost/python.hpp"

namespace py = boost::python;

class MyClass {};

class PyClass : public MyClass {};

void func_a(MyClass param) {}
MyClass func_b() { return MyClass(); }

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(example_module)
{
    py::def("func_a", &func_a);
    py::def("func_b", &func_b);

    py::class_<MyClass>("MyClass");
    py::class_<PyClass, py::bases<MyClass>>("PyClass");
}
```

So for `func_a` to work, I declared `MyClass` as base of `PyClass` and it works fine. Problems start when I want to call `func_b` as it returns to Python object of type `MyClass`. Is there any way of specifically declaring how does return value should be converted?

I've tried creating `to_python_converter`:

```
#include "boost/python.hpp"

namespace py = boost::python;

class MyClass {};

class PyClass : public MyClass 
{
public:
    PyClass() {};
    PyClass(const MyClass& ref) : MyClass(ref) {};
};

void func_a(MyClass param) {}
MyClass func_b() { return MyClass(); }

class BaseToDerived
{
public:
    static PyObject* convert(MyClass const& obj)
    {
        PyClass* n_obj = new PyClass(obj);
        return py::incref(py::object(n_obj).ptr());;

    }
};

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(example_module)
{
    py::def("func_a", &func_a);
    py::def("func_b", &func_b);

    py::class_<MyClass>("MyClass");
    py::class_<PyClass, py::bases<MyClass>>("PyClass");

    py::to_python_converter<MyClass, BaseToDerived>();
}
```

but it ends up crashing with `Microsoft Visual C++ Runtime Library Assertion failed`

Comment: Why can't `func_b` return `PyClass`?

Comment: @Dima Oh, I forgot to specify it. `func_a` and `func_b` are already exising functions which I just want to wrap for use in Python without changing them.

Comment: You could have forwarding functions in `PyClass`, which have different names, but call `func_a` and `func_b`.